# NGXS Async Action Subscription

Tags: ngxs

The NGXS docs indicate that the framework automatically subscribes to Observables returned from within an async action (https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/state#async-actions). This is convenient, but does the framework also handle unsubscribing from the observable, or am I leaking subscriptions every time I call an async action that returns an Observable in this way?

Comment: I think this will give you answer , https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/479 ( answer is from creator of ngxs )

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to unsubscribe from the Observables.

It is handled for you.

Comment: even the dispatch() ?